# Retrieve links from XMLNodeList

Tags: xml, r

how to get the links from these nodes:

```
script <- getURL("www.r-bloggers.com")
doc <- htmlParse(script)
li <- getNodeSet(doc, "//ul[@class='xoxo blogroll']")
```

thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the `a` elements and call `xmlGetAttr` on them.

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
script <- getURL("www.r-bloggers.com")
doc <- htmlParse(script)
li <- getNodeSet(doc, "//ul[@class='xoxo blogroll']//a")
sapply(li, xmlGetAttr, "href")
```

You can also use `xpathApply` directly:

```
xpathSApply(doc, 
  "//ul[@class='xoxo blogroll']//a", 
  xmlGetAttr, "href"
)
```